# MySQL and Storing encrypted User Data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, encryption, aes

I have a lot of User Data that I will be storing on a compliant database server.

Right now there are about 10 different iterations of data that I will be storing but in time it could be in the hundreds.

Data Usually looks like this, give or take 50 other different rows of data:

```
ID          INT (10)
Name        VARCHAR (40)
Address     VARCHAR (65)
City        VARCHAR (40)
State       VARCHAR (2)
Zip         VARCHAR (5)
Birthdate   INT (11)
SSN         VARCHAR (11)

etc.
```

My question isn't necessarily about encrypting the data but the most practical way at storing and retrieving the data.

Right now I have 10 different tables for 10 different classes of data that I am storing. In the next 6 months, this could grow to 100 or even a 1,000 different tables.

- Would it be a better idea to store all of this data in a JSON array and store it in a blob since the rows of data will not always be the same?
- Or should I keep all the data in it's individual columns and encrypt the columns separately?
- Or something else entirely

Comment: Do you need to search on any of the data?

Comment: I think you should rethink your design if you really expect to grow from 10 tables to 100 or 1000 different tables.

Comment: @AndrewBarber No, just retrieve. Since it's going to be encrypted, it's unlikely i'd be able to search anyways

Comment: @Ray different companies require a different table because they are storing completely different information. If you have any ideas, please let me know

Comment: @bryan If you want to store `everything` encrypted and you're not going to access it relationally in any way and don't need consistency between the rows regrading which columns are used(other than maybe a primary key user identifier), you could use a simple 2 column, ID and DATA table.  Maybe a third column, like company_id.  This actually sounds like a possible  candiate for MongoDB or amazon Dynamo instead of Mysql--unless the rest of your tables are more relationally used.

Comment: Thanks @Ray. Our compliance server is MySQL so that is most likely what I will be using for the foreseeable future plus the rest of my tables are more relationally used. Would you mind explaining (maybe in an answer so I can give you some credit) what type of row the DATA column would be and also and ideas you may have in the structure of the un-encrypted data (JSON?) and how you may suggest sending an encrypted 50-250 pieces of data through POST if that is even an issue?

Comment: @bryan I misunderstood.  I didn't realize each user might have hundreds of properties, only a smaller subset. If you're going to frequently be updating these properties I wouldn't do ID & DATA where data is all the user data encrypted.

Comment: @Ray An update will consist of a brand new revision row of the same data with the updated properties since every iteration needs to be audited. It's not each user it's more like of each row of data may have hundreds of properties but probably an average of around 30 properties.

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be a better idea to store all of this data in a JSON array and store it in a blob since the rows of data will not always be the same?

If you're faced with a problem involving non-relational database structures, then use a non-relational database. Or PostgreSQL's JSON features. This has little-to-nothing to do with encryption in and of itself, of course.

> Or should I keep all the data in it's individual columns and encrypt the columns separately?

Regardless of whether you keep this data in a column or drop it into a JSON field,  you're going to end up encrypting columns independently.

If you want to make your life easier, [CipherSweet](https://ciphersweet.paragonie.com/) makes searchable encryption easy (and,  as a consequence, makes key management and field encryption easier regardless of whether or not you need to search on anything).